# How to embed licenses within SVG?

Tags: releasing-data, licensing, rdf, creative-commons

<sup>This is a split refactored from an older post containing too many [questions about licenses in SVG Tiny 1.2 using RDFa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/revisions/3981/4) as suggested by [Patrick Hoefler](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/70/patrick-hoefler). See also question *[Interest of double lincenses CC-BY-SA + ODbL for SVG maps](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3998/interest-of-double-lincenses-cc-by-sa-odbl-for-svg-maps)*.</sup>

#### Introduction

[LittleMap.org](http://Lmap.org/vi/en_c/Welcome_en.html) aims to allow anyone editing maps for blind people. I think the best way to share maps is as [SVG files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).

#### RDFa, DC and CC tags

I also think the best way to embed licenses (and [geographical coordinates](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/)) within [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) file is to use [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/blog/2008/12/rdfa-and-svg-tiny-and-the-rdfa/) (see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959608)).

#### Question

Is my below [`<metadata>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/metadata.html) correct in order to embed both **CC-BY-SA-4.0** and **ODbL v1.0** within SVG file? Is there a "more" correct/standard way? Please suggest improvements.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny">

  <metadata xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
            xmlns:dcq="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" 
            xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" >
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type    rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"         />
        <cc:license rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/" />
        <cc:license rdf:resource="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/"  />
        <cc:attributionName rdf:resource="Laurent Notarianni and LittleMap.org contributors" />
        <cc:attributionURL  rdf:resource="LittleMap.org" />
      </cc:Work>
      <cc:License    rdf:about="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">
        <cc:permits  rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#Reproduction" />
        <cc:permits  rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#Distribution" />
        <cc:permits  rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#DerivativeWorks" />
        <cc:requires rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#Notice" />
        <cc:requires rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#Attribution" />
        <cc:requires rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#ShareAlike" />
      </cc:License>
      <cc:license        rdf:about="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/by/1.0/" >
        <cc:legalcode rdf:resource="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/by/1.0/" >
        <dcq:hasversion>1.0</dcq:hasversion></cc:legalcode>
      </cc:license>
      <cc:license        rdf:about="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/" >
        <cc:legalcode rdf:resource="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/" >
        <dcq:hasversion>1.0</dcq:hasversion></cc:legalcode>
      </cc:license>
      <geo:Point>
        <geo:lat>55.701</geo:lat>
        <geo:long>12.552</geo:long>
      </geo:Point>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>

</svg>
```

Comment: That's a lot of questions! Might I suggest that you split off your last one (how to correctly attach the license to your SVG) into a separate question? That would make it much easier to answer. While you're at it: Could you please make the title(s) of your question(s) a little more concrete? Something along the lines of "Which license should I choose for geographical SVG files?" and "Correct way to attach license to geographical SVG file"? Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you @PatrickHoefler for your feedback. I did it. What do you think about the split? Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not RDFa, but rather embedded RDF/XML, which is allowed by the [SVG Tiny 1.2 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/metadata.html).

There are the following errors:

1. ```
   <cc:license>
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   <cc:License>
   ```

   in lines 26, 29 and 30, 33. The former is a property, the latter is a class.
2. ```
   <cc:attributionName rdf:resource="Laurent Notarianni and LittleMap.org" />
   <cc:attributionURL rdf:resource="LittleMap.org" />
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   <cc:attributionName/>Laurent Notarianni and LittleMap.org</cc:attributionName>  
   <cc:attributionURL rdf:resource="http://littlemap.org" />
   ```

Literals are not IRIs.

3. ```
   <cc:license rdf:about="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/">
      <cc:legalcode rdf:resource="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/">
         <dcq:hasversion>1.0</dcq:hasversion>
       </cc:legalcode>
   </cc:license>
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   <cc:License rdf:about="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/" >
      <cc:legalcode rdf:resource="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/index.html" />
      <dcq:isVersionOf rdf:resource="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/" />
   </cc:License>
   ```

   In short, [hasVersion](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-hasVersion) is intended to be used with non-literal values (IRIs and blank nodes).
   Next, if a license has a version, it doesn't mean that this version is applicable.

Final version:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny">
<metadata xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
          xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
          xmlns:dc11="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
          xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" 
          xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" >
  <rdf:RDF>
    <cc:Work rdf:about="">
      <dc11:format>image/svg+xml</dc11:format>
      <dc11:type    rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      <cc:license rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/" />
      <cc:license rdf:resource="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/"  />
      <cc:attributionName>Laurent Notarianni and LittleMap.org</cc:attributionName>
      <cc:attributionURL  rdf:resource="http://LittleMap.org" />
    </cc:Work>
    <cc:License    rdf:about="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">
      <cc:permits  rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#Reproduction" />
      <cc:permits  rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#Distribution" />
      <cc:permits  rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#DerivativeWorks" />
      <cc:requires rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#Notice" />
      <cc:requires rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#Attribution" />
      <cc:requires rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/ns#ShareAlike" />
    </cc:License>
    <cc:License rdf:about="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/" >
      <cc:legalcode rdf:resource="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/index.html" />
      <dcterms:isVersionOf rdf:resource="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/" />
    </cc:License>
    <geo:Point>
      <geo:lat rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal">55.701</geo:lat>
      <geo:long rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal">12.552</geo:long>
    </geo:Point>
  </rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
</svg>
```

[RDFa 1.1 Distiller](https://github.com/RDFLib/pyrdfa3) will produce the following Turtle:

```
<file:///cygdrive/c/users/.../Desktop/map.svg> a cc:Work ;
    cc:attributionName "Laurent Notarianni and LittleMap.org" ;
    cc:attributionURL <http://LittleMap.org> ;
    cc:license <http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/>,
               <http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/> ;
    dc11:format "image/svg+xml" ;
    dc11:type <http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage> .

<http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/> a cc:License ;
    cc:permits cc:DerivativeWorks,
        cc:Distribution,
        cc:Reproduction ;
    cc:requires cc:Attribution,
        cc:Notice,
        cc:ShareAlike .

<http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/> a cc:License ;
    cc:legalcode <http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/index.html> ;
    dcterms:isVersionOf <http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/> .
```

More info: [RDF 1.1 XML Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/)

Answer (score 2):

While I don't feel particularly authoritative, I hate to see a question with several votes go completely unanswered for so long, so I'll take a crack.

Unfortunately, I am pretty sure this is not an area with wide adoption. Several google searches have this very question among the top hits. So there doesn't seem to be a lot of prior art to go on.

There does not seem to be anything about the [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/documents/2012/06/14/dcmi-terms/#terms-license) or [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/ns#License) concept of license which suggests that there should only be one per [work](https://creativecommons.org/ns#Work). Outside of their RDF specifications, Creative Commons specifically talks about [dual licensing](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/CCPlus) so it isn't foreign to them.

So FWIW, my answer is "looks good to me!"